# Removing watermark in word with OpenXml & C# corrupts document

Tags: c#, openxml

I have tried following code block to delete the watermark from the document

Code 1:

```
private static void DeleteCustomWatermark(WordprocessingDocument package, string watermarkId)
{
    MainDocumentPart maindoc = package.MainDocumentPart;
    if(maindoc!=null)
        {
          var headers = maindoc.GetPartsOfType<HeaderPart>();
          if(headers!=null)
          {
              var head = headers.First(); //we are sure that this header part contains the Watermark with id=watermarkId
              var watermark = head.GetPartById(watermarkId);
              if(watermark!=null)
                  head.DeletePart(watermark);
          }
      }
  }
```

Code 2:

```
   public static void DeleteCustomWatermark(WordProcessingDocument package, string headerId)
   {
     //headerId is the id of the header section which contains the watermark
     MainDocumentPart = maindoc = package.MainDocumentPart;
     if(maindoc!=null)
      {
         var header = maindoc.HeaderParts.First(i=>maindoc.GetIdOfPart(i).Equals(headerId));
         if(header!=null)
             maindoc.DeletePart(header)
      }
    }
```

I have tried both the code blocks. it removes watermark but leaves the document corrupted. I need to recover after this. After recovery the docs are fine. But I want proper solution so that I can remove watermark with C# code without leaving the document corrupted. Please help.

Thanks

Comment: _"proper solution so that I can watermark from code"_ Watermark or DEwatermark? Which is it? I am guessing it has been watermarked to prevent exectly what you are trying to do in the first place?

Comment: I have only watermarked the document but after a particular step I want to remove that watermark.

Comment: Ah, so it was _you_ who put the watermark in the first place? Would it make more sense to make watermarking the last operation you perform on the document?

Comment: It is a requirement initially I will put Watermark after the at the end when it is alright than remove the watermark....

Comment: Lets take an example... Printing salary slip unless it is approved by accounts department we shall put watermark says "Internal Document". And after accounts department's approval before distributing to employees we shall be removing that watermark.

Comment: Ah ok, now it's clear.

Comment: Can you compare the two document version (in "source" code) before and after watermarking and see if there are more changes being made than simply adding the header part? Maybe you have to do something additionally to removing the header part ...

Answer (score 0):

You also need to remove the "Picture" or "Drawing" in the header parts.

e.g.

```
List<Picture> pictures = new List<Picture>(headerPart.RootElement.Descendants<Picture>());

...

foreach(Picture p in pictures) {
     p.Remove();
}

...

headerPart.DeleteParts(imagePartList);
```