# OpenXml to remove watermarks from Word, Excel and Powerpoint

Tags: c#, openxml, watermark

I'm newer using OpenXml, I'm developing a window application in C# and I need to remove the watermark (at run-time) from the selected word, excel or powerpoint file. The watermark has been added manually by the user (don't ask me why he could not remove it manually... it's a customer request...).

I have been created an "empty" file docx (Hello Word! in the body) and with a watermark "DRAFT". I have been implemented an example of simple application to remove it using the code used in this topic (code 1): [Removing watermark in word with OpenXml & C# corrupts document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49167521/removing-watermark-in-word-with-openxml-c-sharp-corrupts-document)

but the application returns a System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException.

The code is the following:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();


    string document = @"D:\Work\EsempioFiligrana\doc1.docx";

    // Open the file in editable mode.  
    using (WordprocessingDocument wordprocessingDocument =
        WordprocessingDocument.Open(document, true))
    {
        DeleteCustomWatermark(wordprocessingDocument, "DRAFT");
    }
}

private static void DeleteCustomWatermark(WordprocessingDocument package, string watermarkId)
{
    MainDocumentPart maindoc = package.MainDocumentPart;
    if (maindoc != null)
    {
         var headers = maindoc.GetPartsOfType<HeaderPart>();
         if (headers != null)
         {
             var head = headers.First(); //we are sure that this header part contains the Watermark with id=watermarkId
             var watermark = head.GetPartById(watermarkId); \\ !! This statement generates the exception !!
             if (watermark != null)
                 head.DeletePart(watermark);
         }
    }
}
```

What's wrong? What can I do to remove the watermark from the document?

Thanks

Comment: [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.packaging.openxmlpartcontainer.getpartbyid?view=openxml-2.8.1) say System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException is thrown when the part with the specified id does not exist. So, perhaps you need to use the correct ID?

Comment: Yes, but I don't understand how to search the correct id. I assume that it is the name of the watermark to search. I don't think that it is a number that can change from a doc to another. Only the name of the used watermark is known.

Comment: You can use `foreach (var h in headers) {...}` to loop through the header parts then `maindoc.GetIdOfPart(h)` to get the ID of each part.

Comment: Thank you very much